# Recursion for max sum in array

Tags: recursion

I have an array of numbers, A = [2,6,4,7,8,3,2,4,6,3]. I am trying to write an algorithm which recursively finds the max number in the array, however you once you select a number you need to skip the next two numbers. So for example if you pick the first number 2, you cant select 6 or 4, but you can select any number after that. So for example the solution for this array would be to pick the numbers 6,8,6 to make 20.

Comment: This sounds like a situation where dynamic programming would do miracles

Comment: isnt dynamic programming the same as recursion but with data management? or am i getting confused here

Comment: That's one way to look at it. But don't confuse "recurrence relation" and "recursive program". When you have a recurrence relation, such as fib(n+2) = fib(n+1) + fib(n), you can either use that relation "naively" to write a recursive program directly, or you can use that recurrence relation to write a more clever program, be it recursive or dynamic programming or whatever.

Comment: When the recurrence relation is very simple, it's okay to turn it "naively" into a recursive program. However, if you write a recursive program that makes two recursive calls per call, that's probably bad. For instance, fib(n) = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2) would be horrible to write a "naive" recursive solution, because at every step, you're multiplying the number of recursive calls by 2. Quickly the number of calls blows up. So you need to be a little more careful. Dynamic programming does that.

Comment: Ah okay got it, so for this problem dynamic programming would be the best as it will reduce the recursive calls, however I am a bit confused on how to start to solve this problem. For example, in leetcode 746. Min Cost Climbing Stairs. The dp solution returns the min from dp-1/dp-2. So i am trying to use a similar approach here but I need to ignore the first two numbers after you select a number and turn it into a maximisation problem

Comment: Yes. So, the thing is, you can either select the first number, or not select it. Let's say dp(i) is the maximum sum that can be found by selecting numbers from the array, if we only select numbers starting at index i. Then dp(0) will be the final result we're interested in. And now you can write a recurrence relation between dp(i) and dp(i+1) and dp(i+3).

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem either iteratively or recursively. The iterative solution would be more efficient.

A recursive solution in Java might look like following (not checking for empty arrays):

```java
private int maxSumGap(int[] array, int gap, int start) {
  // Basis case is the start position is at the last position of the array
  if (start == array.length - 1;) {
    // Maximum is the only value
    return array[start];
  
  // Case if there are values after the gap
  } else if (start < array.length - 1 - gap) {
    // Compare the recursive calls with start position + 1 with the sum of start
    // position + 1 + gap plus the value at the start position
    return Math.max(
            maxSumGap(array, gap, start + 1),
            maxSumGap(array, gap, start + gap + 1) + array[start]
    );
  // Case if there are no values after the gap
  } else {
    // Compare the recursive calls with start position + 1 with the value at the
    // start position
    return Math.max(
            maxSumGap(array, gap, start + 1),
            array[start]
    );
  }
}
```